# Battery thermal protection circuit

Tags: battery-charging, circuit-protection, solar-charge-controller, bms

I'm trying to design a circuit to be used with some 12V LiFePO4 battery packs which don't have an integrated heater, so I can add thermal protection.

The circuit would sit between a [65W solar charge controller](https://sunforgellc.com/product/gv-5/) and the battery's existing BMS.

[image]

It would sense temperature and during detected freezing conditions it would:

1. disable charging using an n-channel MOSFET
2. enable a heating pad when charge current is available
3. prevent the battery from discharging into the heating pad
4. not prevent the battery from discharging into the load

I won't have access to the load terminals so my circuit sees the charger and load together. The load is about 2W.

I'm stuck on how to achieve #2 and #3 together without disconnecting the load. I need some way to sense that there is charge current.

I'm currently exploring a strategy involving the comparison of battery negative voltage to the drain voltage of the charge control MOSFET. This approach seems promising as, during charging, the drain voltage is expected to be lower than the battery negative terminal voltage.

[image]

[Falstad simulation here of charging scenario](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWECAstIIEwDZsHZNJ8MAOEFJCBSZAUwFowwAoAcxAGYSVOPtPunLFCjMAZiGyQymApOm9%20HTCEzQkMFGCnxdelOMkkZc7McXkaajdC069DgwHcBPDn3Ika7-pGYvsTDcPfBUfUQA3VwsuHkwEXxEUGjAOERoYBGYAJ3A4MjA8fjB8ixS4fxBuAqLowt9mAGd5ExUpGSD0kDEAQwAbRtomo1aR1U6U7v7B5gAlFvGeLA6eDMtOaDS1zMr2xbHMCeGShPBapg96rt6BoZcLpUuMR4bc2LOlQXjEmDgDKIeFkBVzWyXAaA06XUOSqKFG1Q%20IhKlQRVxKChBKLhQNK4T8zQRshUCLxIhuM1yqGC-Cpqjk5T0MLwHnCzP4RKRDkqtI5ew5fgC5g5bLpKgFyBQ1OQAE4wh5xXhIFKRXjKiqPCT5cwAEZAyXkMEcaWrSromrFZ6I8VmnGnVUAD2QeGlQh42A4EA4CDw5HAKgAJgBLRoAYwAFj1sqwho6OBRwEbyO5wSoeGAVOmAGoAHUaABkAGIABVzACEegAXCu0bIAT2YjtwLq9aUVSC9-DTKnDkejOqqcHAUiqJDSXrIfkdeHMYAQaWlSvApy7IG1lerddzYdolZrue1fR6ADsANa0CvMQg%20m1o0pgfU8HtRvcAB0vkGvuKeCj4ZEfEefbJ6AbEBpTMVQEDIaUF1UbAIBXPoAHsen9XZOjsTwaAw8U4Sw7RMLKSpcIsWlVWSCBsDBDDKJoWkIBIXNZ1zRgEEYhxc0gZiwFsaDeN4%20IUHiPA2N0KBc0IESHEHMAON2Zd8JFbC1Q8DD1QaABZMZaQIWj9SsaF5jMP9KJAHTyBM0FvE2LodlyIzzLdcxaQZcUaIlRyyGckCzFo7AkBIQ5kHAlc1yrGtay3HcN1zENj1zWgjx6A9aAAfmYIA).

This approach works in the simulation, but:

- My model of the battery and charger are very crude and possibly wrong. How should I model these?
- The rds_on of the MOSFETs are unrealistically high, so the potential difference I'd need to sense would be much smaller, possibly too small to be reliable?
- I'm unsure what would happen at edge cases where there's just a bit of charge current available. For example, some kind of hysteresis is probably needed for current sensing but I'm not sure how to add this.

Many BMS systems boast built-in thermal protection capabilities. Given this, I assume my goal is attainable. Is my general approach sensible, or are there more effective alternatives to consider?

Comment: Bedtime in NZ. I may provide an answer in a day or few if nobody else does - but they probably will. || BUT: A useful 'trick' can be to insulate the battery and provide it with a thermally linked water jacket. Standing it in water may be viable. With relatively modest insulation using polystyrene  you can get some days at 0 degrees C when external temperature is say -20C or lower. I have some related calculations on this site from a few years back but will not try to dig them out at present. Advise if more information wanted.

Comment: I lied :-). See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/467518/3288 . || Also some relevance https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/527325/feasibility-of-sub-zero-peltier-cooler/527341#527341 .

Comment: @RussellMcMahon thanks there is some great info and ideas in these links. Note that at the very least I need to design a circuit to disable charging so I may as well try to integrate self-heating if I feasibly can. In terms of the battery box design I'm somewhat limited in size for adding a water tank and thick insulation. It's ok if the load shuts down from cold sometimes (the less it does this the better). I can't have battery packs failing.

Comment: I don't know how long you need to protect it for. If you need weeks or indefinite water is not suitable. Days, it may be.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon indefinite

Answer (score 0):

This circuit may meet your need.
Limitations are discussed at the end.

PV panel hard connects to load.

When weather is warm "COLD" input is low.
M1 gate is high. M1 is off. Heater doesn't heat.
M2 gate is low.  M2 is on. Battery connects to load and PV panel.

When weather is cold, "COLD" input is high.
M1 gate is low. M1 is on. Heater heats.
M2 gate is high. M2 is off.
Battery can provide load via D1 and M2 body diode in parallel.
PV panel supplies load but does not charge battery.

**Cold operation:**

Battery powering of the load is reduced in efficiency by D1.
If D1 drops 0.5V in a 12V system efficiency loss is 0.5/12 =~ 4%.

When the PV panel voltage is not high enough to power the load, M2 could be turned on.  Battery voltage will be pplied to the PV panel - usually current drawn will be small, but another FET (M3) could be added to prevent this.
Managing M2 and M3 switching may be problematic. When the PV panel is switched off panel voltage will rise slightly, leading to an osciallating boundary condition.
A decision may need to be made re battery powering of load and heater together.
A current flow sensor could be used to ensure that no current ever flows from PV panel to battery when cold, but again, an oscillatory condition may occur.
Overall this is very probably not insoluble, but the suggested circuit may meet the ned well enough. Or not :-).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY3PTo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Relay solution:**

A double pole double throw (DPDT) relay would perform the same function.
COLD = low, relay off, PV panel powers load and battery charging.
Battery connects to load and panel via contact-1.
COLD = high. Relay on.
Contact 2 connects PV panel to heater and disconnects battery charging.
Contact 1 disconnects direct battery-load path and switches in a Schottky diode, preventing charging.